# DataTables checkbox don't restyle the row?

Tags: datatables

Using DataTables with checkboxes as described [here in the documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox). Given that it's not a "real" checkbox (per the doc) is it possible to check the box but not "repaint" the row?

In my app by default all rows are checked; less readable when styled as selections.

Comment: What is "repaint" the row? Do you refer to background color?

Comment: Yep, sorry, wasn't clear, would like to use JS to check the box but not select (and repaint the background color) the row. Possible?

Comment: If the anwer is helpfull please vote up or check it as correct please.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you, you only want remove selection style, no?

Use css for add style to tr selected and td child of datatables, something like this:

```
table.dataTable tbody > tr.selected, table.dataTable tbody > tr.selected > td {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```